# Plotting two graphs of unequal time length in 1 graph

Tags: data-visualization, excel

Say I have the following data set.

[image]

I need to plot both in one graph and when I tried to do so this is what I got.

[image]

The data of A are not connected by a line so this is not what I want. How do I get the graph with both data sets connected by lines?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change a setting in Excel's **"Show empty cells as"** options as follows:

1) Choose `Select Data` item (Click on the chart, then select `Design` tab in `Chart Tools`);

2) In the `Select Data Source` pop-up window, click on `Hidden and Empty Cells` button below;

3) In the `Hidden and Empty Cell Settings` pop-up window, select `Connect data points with line` (instead of the default `Gaps`).

Voilà! Enjoy the nice plot!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use R for this:

```
ddf
  Grp X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   A  5 NA  6 NA  2
2   B  6  4  5  7  3

mm = melt(ddf, id='Grp')
mm
   Grp variable value
1    A       X1     5
2    B       X1     6
3    A       X2    NA
4    B       X2     4
...

ggplot(mm[!is.na(mm$value),], aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Grp, color=Grp))+geom_point()+geom_line()
```

[image]